# How to limit UPDATE when using PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to get right solution / answer for my issue, still not able to get around, kindly help !

This is the same MYSQL UPDATE, LIMIT issue I was trying to resolve. I thought maybe with PHP and MYSQL script it should be able work, not sure, pl check the below code. It is updating Rate field in Ratemaster table with the last value of Rates table. But there are 3 rows in both the tables where 3 different rates in Rates table.

I have 2 tables: Ratemaster and rates, in which a CUSTOMER can have 1 PRODUCT with different RATES. Because of this, there is a duplication of customer and product fields, only the rate field changes. 
Now Table **Ratemaster** has all the fields : id, cust_code, Product, Rate, user whereas Table **Rates** has only: id, cust_code, Rate, user. - user field is for checking session_user.

My php and mysql code below:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","db","pwd");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("db", $con);

$user = $_SESSION['user'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM Rates";
$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error()); 

while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
mysql_query("UPDATE Ratemaster, Rates SET Ratemaster.Rate = '".$line['Rate']."'  WHERE Ratemaster.user = '".$line['user']."'")or die(mysql_error());}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have add one more field in Ratemaster called 'rid' . It's should match with Rates table 'id' field. And one more thing, id always should be unique.

Ratemaster has : 3 records

```
(id:1, cust_code:1231, Product:Clay, Rate:0, user:user1,rid:1) 
(id:2, cust_code:1231, Product:Clay, Rate:0, user:user1,rid:2) 
(id:3, cust_code:1231, Product:Clay, Rate:0, user:user1,rid:3)
```

Rates has 3recs :

```
(id:1, cust_code:1231, Rate:299, user:user1) 
(id:2, cust_code:1231, Rate:355, user:user1) 
(id:3, cust_code:1231, Rate:466, user:user1)
```

Code :

```
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","db","pwd");
 if (!$con)
    {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
mysql_select_db("db", $con);

$user = $_SESSION['user'];

mysql_query("UPDATE Ratemaster, Rates SET Ratemaster.Rate = Rates.Rate  WHERE Ratemaster.user = '".$line['user']."' AND Ratemaster.rid=Rates.id ")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Hi Siva, Thanks for your reply, but your addition of AND is not having any effect, it is just the same condition what i have in WHERE clause.

Comment: I couldn't understand ur problem. Can u pls add some sample data for fix that issue. it'll will be very useful.

Comment: Hi Siva, Ratemaster has : 3 records (id:1, cust_code:1231, Product:Clay, Rate:0, user:user1) (id:1, cust_code:1231, Product:Clay, Rate:0, user:user1) (id:1, cust_code:1231, Product:Clay, Rate:0, user:user1) whereas Table Rates has 3recs : (id:1, cust_code:1231, Rate:299, user:user1) (id:1, cust_code:1231, Rate:355, user:user1) (id:1, cust_code:1231, Rate:466, user:user1), Hope this sample data helps now, I want only Rate from Rates table to be inserted into Ratemaster.

Comment: Hi Siva, Thank you so much, I think it should work, however I shall just try and get back !

Comment: Hi Siva, I have done this, but the result is still the same. The last Rate (466) of Rates table gets updated for all 3 records in Ratemaster. The UPDATE command everytime updates all 3 records with 1 value in the loop. How to limit this ?

Comment: Hi Siva, I tried removing the condition Ratemaster.user = '".$line['user']."' from UPDATE line, still it UPDATEs only the last value to all 3 records of Rates table. Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi Siva, It worked now after I removed that while loop and condition Ratemaster.user = '".$line['user']."', Thank you so much for all the help !

Comment: in my answer, i have removed while loop, dont u see ?

Comment: Yes Siva, I had missed it, Sorry, even the user condition is also not required.  **mysql_query("UPDATE Ratemaster, Rates SET Ratemaster.Rate = Rates.Rate  WHERE Ratemaster.rid=Rates.id ")**  Thank you so much....